# Can we use low-end front derailleur with an 11 speed crankset?

Tags: compatibility

Can we use a low-end front derailleur like Shimano Tourney 2x with an 11 speed 2x Shimano (105, Ultegra or Dura-ace) crankset? If not, how low can I go?

Just needs confirmation base from this link I've read.

[Compatibility [05] Front derailleurs](https://bike.bikegremlin.com/1297/bicycle-front-derailleur-compatibility/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any 2x front shifter has only two or three clicks and as long as the cable pull isn't wildly out of spec an X speed derailleur will work with an 11 speed crankset. If you have just a double in front the key thing is that the cage curvature match the size of the large chainring and you can mount the derailluer with the appropriate clearance (roughly 3mm between tooth tip and derailluer cage). I have successfully shifted 11 speed double chainrings in in 50/34, 46/30 and 38/22 with 9 speed front derailleurs and Campy 10 speed brifters. Having a chain catcher like the K-edge one helps a lot.

Triples are more fussy when it comes to matching derailluer cage and shifters.

It's almost never a question of will it work, but will it work smoothly enough for you. Mix and matching components will always require a bit more fiddling and likely will not ever work as smoothly as fully matched high end components. But it's just a bike, enjoy the ability to hack and bodge things while you can.

Comment: Which Campy shifter? The non indexed Ultrashift and old versions work with any front derailleur.

Comment: The newer 10spd ones with only 3-4 clicks.

Comment: Good to know that that combination works too.

Answer (score 0):

Skipping over why anyone would want to compromise the front shifting performance of their Dura-Ace, Ultegra or 105 groupset with a Tourney derailleur ...

Derailleur to crank compatibility is not the crux issue, it's derailleur to *shifter* compatibility. I highly doubt that Tourney and road 11 speed groups have the same front derailleur actuation ratio (cage movement / cable length pulled), so the derailleur would not be compatible with any 11 speed left hand shifters.

Shimano has a very comprehensive set of compatibility docs. [Here is the section for road front drivetrain](https://productinfo.shimano.com/#/com?cid=C-453&acid=C-455). ST/SL components are the shifters, FD components are the front derailleurs.

Shimano basically says only 11 speed front derailleurs work with 11 speed LH shifters.

Comment: Compromise, mainly because of budget constraints. Thanks for the link by the way. It's a very big help. But have you tried or saw someone used a lower-end FD to an 11 speed crankset? Not specifically Tourney but lower than 11 speed FD.

Comment: @WashichawbachaW, I have never seen this tried.

Comment: @WashichawbachaW Budget constraints? I think you're chasing false economies. A Tourney front der is ~$17 (US). A 105 front der is about $34, and ultegra ~$40.

Is this really where you're going to save money?

Comment: @Paul H I have a tourney from an old bike. Also, I'm just exploring the possibilities of compatibility with low-end FDs to higher-end models.